# How to handle copy & paste in ncurses?

Tags: paste, ncurses

It seems `ncurses` handles paste (from copy & paste) by inserting one character at a time from the text that was pasted, which can be slow if the handler for each character is slow.
I'd like to handle paste events myself, when a 'bracketed paste' sequence is detected, starting with `ESC[200~` (see http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html#Bracketed%20Paste%20Mode).

How can I implement this in `ncurses`?

Comment: It's unclear why you need this.  Are you looking for a performance improvement, custom handling, or both?

Comment: reason 1: performance. I want to handle the paste atomically and not treat it as if characters were entered 1 at a time (eg, allowing me to refresh the screen only once instead once per character)
reason 2: allow custom logic (eg if pasted text 'too large')

Comment: The entire screen refreshes for *every character?*

Comment: doesn't have to be entire screen, it can be optimized to be finer grained but I want to have a single doupdate() per paste event.

Answer (score 1):

Here some code illustrating 'bracketed paste mode' (using Ruby curses).

There is only three key things:

0.) Make sure your terminal supports bracketed paste mode (such as for instance Windows 10 Terminal since about 1 month, see https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.7.572.0)

1.) Switch on bracketed paste mode in the terminal by sending the `?2004h` CSI.

```
print("\x1b[?2004h")
```

2.) When a paste occurs, recognize that you received `\x1b[200~` to start parsing the pasted text and `\x1b[201~` to recognize that the pasted text is finished.

```rb
# /usr/bin/ruby2.7
require "curses"
include Curses

def main_loop
  init_screen
  noecho      # Disable Echoing of character presses

  # Switch on braketed paste mode
  print("\x1b[?2004h")

  addstr("Please paste something into this terminal (make sure it supports braketed paste!) or press 'q' to quit.\n")

  loop do
    c = get_char2

    case c
    in 'q' # use q to quit
      return

    in csi: "200~" # Bracketed paste started

      pasted = ""
      loop do
        d = get_char2
        case d
        in csi: "201~" # Bracketed paste ended
          break
        else
          pasted += d
        end
      end

      addstr("You pasted: #{pasted.inspect}\n")

    else
      addstr("You didn't paste something, you entered: #{c.inspect} #{c.class.name}\n")
    end
  end

ensure
  close_screen
end

#
# For CSI, or "Control Sequence Introducer" commands,
# the ESC [ is followed by
# 1.) any number (including none) of "parameter bytes" in the range
#     0x30–0x3F (ASCII 0–9:;<=>?), then by
# 2.) any number of "intermediate bytes" in the range
#     0x20–0x2F (ASCII space and !"#$%&'()*+,-./), then finally by
# 3.) a single "final byte" in the range
#     0x40–0x7E (ASCII @A–Z[\]^_`a–z{|}~).
#
# From: https://handwiki.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code
def get_csi

  result = ""
  loop do
    c = get_char
    result += c
    if c.ord >= 0x40 && c.ord <= 0x7E
      return result
    end
  end
end

# Just like get_char, but will read \x1b[<csi> and return it as a hash { csi: ... }, everything else is just returned as-is
def get_char2
  c = get_char
  case c
  when "\e" # ESC
    case get_char
    when '['
      return { csi: get_csi }
    else
      raise "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
    end
  else
    return c
  end
end

main_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it works after enabling bracketed paste mode, but this needs to be done with raw terminal sequences since ncurses doesn't provide support for that by itself.

Comment: Any chance you could provide the code snippet for doing that?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: See my answer below.

Comment: Both the premise (that the problem cannot be addressed in ncurses) and the suggested solution (using bracketed paste) are defective.